# How to setup alias using serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

I have a project I'm working on with another developer using the serverless framework in aws. I need us both be able to deploy the stack without each other stepping on the others changes. I've been looking for an alias feature where I can provide some prefix or something that will make the deployment unique, but so far I've been unsuccessful. Is there such a feature in serverless to do this? If not how do teams deploy multiple version of the same code without stepping on each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Serverless Stages. Set your stage to your name and your teammate can set the stage to his name.

Production and Dev can also be separate stages.

https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/stages-in-serverless-framework.html

Comment: Hi Noel thanks for replying. After your response I looked through my yaml file and noticed I had sstAppMapping which would default to dev when passing in different stages that weren't found. After removing this I was able to create unique stages. Thanks again for the quick response.